# Clarity with Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an array of project objects that can be sorted in 3 ways: name, date, and random.

The name and date sorts are grouped by first letter or year, respectively. The random sort does not have any grouping, which means the random sort requires a different DOM structure.

I've got it wired up, but I'm using two distinct DOM structures in the view, which is terribly inefficient and probably not the "Angular Way". I'm using directives to show or hide the proper DOM template based on the chosen sort option, but I'm hoping someone can give some guidance regarding how to better approach this problem.

**Update**: note that there are two different uses of `ng-repeat` depending on the chosen sort. Name and Date use a nested loop to loop through the groups (`(header, group) in projects`) and then each group loops through its projects (`project in group`). Random uses a single loop since random is ungrouped (`project in projects`).

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9tmCdNH20JBzzh4pQRml?p=preview). Note the delay when you choose the Random option. Some relevant parts listed below.

**project-grid partial**

```
<div class="project-controls">
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="orderChoice" value="name">Name</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="orderChoice" value="date">Date</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="orderChoice" value="random">Random</label>
</div>

<!-- DOM structure for grouped Name and Date sortings -->
<!-- Note the nested ng-repeat -->
<div id="nonRandomGrouping" ng-hide="randomSort">
    <div class="group" ng-repeat="(header, group) in projects">
        <h2>{{ header }}</h2>
        <ul class="project-thumbnails">
            <li ng-repeat="project in group | orderBy: 'name' ">
            <img ng-src="{{project.coverImage}}">
            <p><strong>{{ project.name }}</strong></p>
            <p><strong>{{ project.date }}</strong></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- DOM structure for ungrouped Random sorting -->
<!-- Note the single ng-repeat -->
<div class="group" id="randomGrouping" ng-show="randomSort">
    <ul class="project-thumbnails">
        <li ng-repeat="project in projects" style="overflow: auto;">
            <img ng-src="{{project.coverImage}}">
            <p><strong>{{ project.name }}</strong></p>
            <p><strong>{{ project.date }}</strong></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        var projectsByName,
            projectsByYear,
            originalData

        $scope.orderChoice = "name"
        $scope.randomSort = false

        function randomize() {
            $scope.randomSort = true
            $scope.projects = originalData.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() })
        }

        $scope.getProjects = function() {
          $http({ method : "GET", url : "/projects.json" }).success(function(data) {
              $scope.count = data.length
              originalData = data.sort()
              $scope.projects = projectsByName = _.groupBy(data, function grouper(proj){
                return proj.name[0]
              })
              projectsByYear = _.groupBy(data, function grouper(proj){
                return new Date(proj.date).getFullYear()
              })
          })
        }

        $scope.$watch('orderChoice', function orderChangeHandler(newVal, oldVal){
            if ( newVal !== oldVal ) {
                switch(newVal){
                    case 'name':
                        $scope.randomSort = false
                        $scope.projects = projectsByName
                        break;
                    case 'date':
                        $scope.randomSort = false
                        $scope.projects = projectsByYear
                        break;
                    case 'random':
                        randomize()
                        break;
                }
            }
        })

        $scope.getProjects()
    }])
```

Comment: Why do you hate semi-colons?

Comment: I'm not trying to start a flame war: http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

Comment: Nor was I, just genuinely curious. It doesn't matter to me if you write code that will end up breaking or being misunderstood by the other people that work on it. To try and answer your question: I would try and get the sorting working within 1 dom structure, but it seems like you kind of already knew this. If you use a string as the param to orderBy and manipulate that string to change the sort column, you might be able to get what you want. (Unsorted would just be empty string?)

Comment: @aet I'm working solo on this, so it's the style I choose. If I were working with a group I'd work to a group-defined style. Anyway... I was working with orderBy for a bit, but I was getting an error from running too many digest cycles. Also, the issue isn't really the ordering, tho, it's the fact that the the random order requires a different DOM/Angular structure: note how the `#nonRandomGrouping` uses a nested loop: `(header, group) in projects` wrapping `project in group`, where `#randomGrouping` is a single loop `project in projects`.

Comment: Hm, that should not happen. You would have to show the code that caused the inf digest. That does happen when you try and ng-repeat over a changing array.

Comment: @aet ah, I'd have to go back and try to recreate it. Wasn't working in source control at the time. Any thoughts on the distinction between nested loop vs single loop?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51446/discussion-between-aet-and-noslouch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- You could model "Random sort" as "single grouped" instead of not grouped in order to avoid duplication.

2.- Instead of running random at watch, you could shuffle once and then memoize the result.

Comment: **1.** Using random as a single group is novel! Is there a way I can get rid of the randomSort flag in my controller? I wouldn't want a group title for the random group. **2.** True, but there is a requirement that random act more like a shuffle, i.e. a different result each time. In fact I think I may need to us a different form control for that so that it includes a re-shuffle function (click random multiple times for multiple orders).  __So you're saying that a custom directive wouldn't even make sense for this kind of DOM manipulation?__

Comment: 1.- I wouldn't model projects as a (header, group) tuple but as a group object list, and header would be a property. "Random" group header would be empty. 2.- No, a directive makes sense. I just think shuffling as a response to user interaction might not be the most efficient way.

Comment: 1. I see what you mean, but remodeling is not straight forward, since I'm using lodash's grouping function, which spits out a single composed object, each key of which is a unique group header. I'm generating a CSS class using {{ orderChoice }} to control the display of the random header. 2. I've refactored according to your suggestion in #1 and the performance is better, plus no duplication: http://embed.plnkr.co/0xpWuwLpZqwwtvERoaTe/preview

Comment: Pretty neat :) You could post-process lodash grouping afterwards, but css might be better, you're right.